# CSS Collapsable Side Bar with Fixed Header and Footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a page that has a fixed header and a fixed footer that also has a side menu that is collapsible.

I forked the following Bootply

https://www.bootply.com/lRSKFC6Fnc

Mine is the following

https://www.bootply.com/NhmUUdfruP

There are 3 issues. 
 1. The header I want to have it fixed so that the sidebar when it slides in doesnt shrink the header 
 2. same with the footer
 3. the 2nd row in my header is has the body content overlapping it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you solve that or not ?\

Comment: No, not yet....

Comment: ok, let me solve now. do you want to change your question or not

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: you have 3 problems ok, do you solve one of that or not, so i will solve all 3 problems or less

Comment: Yes if you could help me solve all 3 problems that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have any doubt, tell me

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  $("#menu-toggle").toggleClass("toggled");

  $("body").css("overflow-x", "scroll");
  setTimeout(function () { $("body").css("overflow-x", "auto"); }, 1500
   );
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var currentFooterHeight = $('footer').css('height');
  var newContentHeight = 'calc(100vh - 60px - ' + currentFooterHeight + ')';
  $('#page-content-wrapper').css('height', newContentHeight);
 })
```

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
 }
 /* Toggle Styles */

 #wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
 #wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
 }

 #menu-toggle{
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: -41px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }

 #menu-toggle.toggled{
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: 207px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: black;
 }

 #sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-top: 94px;
 }

 #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 #page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:60px;
 }

 #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
 }

 /* Sidebar Styles */

 .sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
 }

 .sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
 }

 .sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
 }

 .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 }

 .sidebar-nav li a:active,
 .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
 }

 .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
 }

 .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="header fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" type="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Back</a></div>
    <div id="qSearch" class="col-11"><input class="form-control" type="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
          Start Bootstrap
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row m-0 mt-3">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11 mt-3">

          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim.
          Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede.
          Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue.<p></p>
          Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede.<p></p>
          Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla. Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien.
          Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat. Etiam eget dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed at lorem in nunc porta tristique.<p></p>
          Proin nec augue. Quisque aliquam tempor magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc ac magna.<p></p>
          Maecenas odio dolor, vulputate vel, auctor ac, accumsan id, felis. Pellentesque cursus sagittis felis. Pellentesque porttitor, velit lacinia egestas auctor, diam eros tempus arcu, nec vulputate augue magna vel risus. Cras non magna vel ante adipiscing rhoncus.
          Vivamus a mi. Morbi neque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer ultrices lobortis eros.<p></p>
          Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin semper, ante vitae sollicitudin posuere, metus quam iaculis nibh, vitae scelerisque nunc massa eget pede. Sed velit urna, interdum vel, ultricies vel, faucibus at, quam. Donec elit est, consectetuer eget, consequat quis, tempus quis, wisi.
          In in nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Donec ullamcorper fringilla eros. Fusce in sapien eu purus dapibus commodo.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras faucibus condimentum odio. Sed ac ligula. Aliquam at eros.
          Etiam at ligula et tellus ullamcorper ultrices. In fermentum, lorem non cursus porttitor, diam urna accumsan lacus, sed interdum wisi nibh nec nisl. Ut tincidunt volutpat urna. Mauris eleifend nulla eget mauris.
          Sed cursus quam id felis. Curabitur posuere quam vel nibh. Cras dapibus dapibus nisl. Vestibulum quis dolor a felis congue vehicula.<p></p>
          Maecenas pede purus, tristique ac, tempus eget, egestas quis, mauris. Curabitur non eros. Nullam hendrerit bibendum justo. Fusce iaculis, est quis lacinia pretium, pede metus molestie lacus, at gravida wisi ante at libero.
          Quisque ornare placerat risus. Ut molestie magna at mi. Integer aliquet mauris et nibh. Ut mattis ligula posuere velit.<p></p>
          Nunc sagittis. Curabitur varius fringilla nisl. Duis pretium mi euismod erat. Maecenas id augue.<p></p>
          Nam vulputate. Duis a quam non neque lobortis malesuada. Praesent euismod. Donec nulla augue, venenatis scelerisque, dapibus a, consequat at, leo.<p></p>
          Pellentesque libero lectus, tristique ac, consectetuer sit amet, imperdiet ut, justo. Sed aliquam odio vitae tortor. Proin hendrerit tempus arcu. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
          Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus vitae massa adipiscing est lacinia sodales. Donec metus massa, mollis vel, tempus placerat, vestibulum condimentum, ligula. Nunc lacus metus, posuere eget, lacinia eu, varius quis, libero.<p></p>
          Aliquam nonummy adipiscing augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.<p></p>
          Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<p></p>

          Nunc sagittis. Curabitur varius fringilla nisl. Duis pretium mi euismod erat. Maecenas id augue.<p></p>
          Nam vulputate. Duis a quam non neque lobortis malesuada. Praesent euismod. Donec nulla augue, venenatis scelerisque, dapibus a, consequat at, leo.<p></p>
          Pellentesque libero lectus, tristique ac, consectetuer sit amet, imperdiet ut, justo. Sed aliquam odio vitae tortor. Proin hendrerit tempus arcu. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
          Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus vitae massa adipiscing est lacinia sodales. Donec metus massa, mollis vel, tempus placerat, vestibulum condimentum, ligula. Nunc lacus metus, posuere eget, lacinia eu, varius quis, libero.<p></p>
          Aliquam nonummy adipiscing augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.<p></p>
          Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<p></p>



          Nunc sagittis. Curabitur varius fringilla nisl. Duis pretium mi euismod erat. Maecenas id augue.<p></p>
          Nam vulputate. Duis a quam non neque lobortis malesuada. Praesent euismod. Donec nulla augue, venenatis scelerisque, dapibus a, consequat at, leo.<p></p>
          Pellentesque libero lectus, tristique ac, consectetuer sit amet, imperdiet ut, justo. Sed aliquam odio vitae tortor. Proin hendrerit tempus arcu. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
          Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus vitae massa adipiscing est lacinia sodales. Donec metus massa, mollis vel, tempus placerat, vestibulum condimentum, ligula. Nunc lacus metus, posuere eget, lacinia eu, varius quis, libero.<p></p>
          Aliquam nonummy adipiscing augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.<p></p>
          Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<p></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<footer class="w-100 fixed-bottom">
  <span class="">footer</span>
</footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Almost. This solved 2 of the 3 problems. The following is still an issue though. If you notice in my Bootly there are the following lines of code.




<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-1"><a href="#">Back</a></div>
<div id="qSearch" class="col-lg-9"><input class="form-control" type="text"></div>
    </div>




I need those to stay fixed about the page content so when I scroll they don't move.

Comment: Now that works but when the side menu is toggled that row should shrink so that the side menu doesnt overlap it.

Comment: if you want to fix this position, you don't want to focus on other process like sidebar overlapping